# How to mock the BooleanUtils class or an application property?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to create a *when* sentence, but I can't do it well because I don't know how to mock correctly whatever.

I have this code:

```java
public class OperationMovement {

@Value("${operation.check}")
private Boolean needToCheck;

   private void checkOperation() {

      // Code

      if (BooleanUtils.isTrue(needToCheck)) {
         // More code
      }
   }
}
```

I need to create a test with Mockito, but I don't know how to mock this *if else*.

I have tried to mock the *BooleanUtils* this way:

```java
@Mock
BeanUtils beanUtils;

// Code and more testing code

when(booleanUtils.isTrue(anyBoolean())).thenReturn(true);
```

But this returs an error.

I have tried the following too, but I have the same error:

```java
when(BooleanUtils.isTrue(anyBoolean())).thenReturn(true);
```

I need to mock that propertie or the BooleanUtils class, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can use ```ReflectionTestUtils.setField``` to set the value of the field.

Since ```BooleanUtils.isTrue``` is a static method, you won't be able to mock it using normal Mockito. I think PowerMock may be able to, but not 100% on that.

Comment: Can you post an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example usage:

```
private OperationMovement classUnderTest;
...

@Test
void testOperationIsTrue() {
    // For this test case, you are setting it to true
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest,"needToCheck",true);
}
```

Comment: Mmmmmm... Yes papa! This works well!